# Compute large number of additional columns pandas dataframe using apply

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe of 2 columns - index, textblock. I wish to create 50 additional columns, with column names as numbers ranging from 1980 to 2030. Each column essentially contains the number of times that number (eg. 2015) is present in the textblock. Since I would like to do this for every row, I can use the `.apply()` function.

Here is the function.

```
def funct(row):
    mydict = {}
    to_return_list = []
    textcont = row['textblock']
    for no in range(1980,2031):
        mydict[no] = textcont.count(no)
        to_return_list.append(textcont.count(no))

    return tuple(to_return_list)
    # or maybe return pd.Series(mydict) ?
```

Typically, if I wish to compute additional columns by applying a function in pandas, the code is:

```
(df['col1'], df['col2'], df['col3']) = zip(*dfs.apply(funct, axis=1))
```

If I wish to do the same for my function, I would have to add the column names manually, i.e.

```
(df['1980'], df['1981'], df['1982'] .... ) = zip(*dfs.apply(funct, axis=1))
```

This is obviously very cumbersome. (Also, if I later wish to change the range to : 1970 to 2030 instead, I have to add the names manually again). Is there a way to do this without entering the names manually, perhaps using a dictionary?

Toy Example:

```
import pandas as pd
dataframe = pd.DataFrame([{'index' : 541, 'textblock' : '2019, 2713, hello there general 3120 1980 to 2020'}, {'index' : 6361, 'textblock' : 'Here is some more 2000 dummy text 2029 and additional 1975 text'}])
```

My output as I explained should have the following columns

```
index | textblock | 1980 | 1981 ..... | 2030
```

Comments : I do not prefer a solution that iterates through every row manually. This was just a toy example highlighting my issue. My original dataframe has over 20 columns containing other data as well, thus having to create a new dictionary to copy the existing data is still not very elegant, though any efficient solution will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. use regexp to find all no.
2. use `explode` to transform a list-like to a row, replicating the index values.
3. then groupby ['index', 'textblock', 'no'] count the size, then unstack.

```
pat =r'\b%s\b' % r'\b|\b'.join(map(str, range(1980,2031)))
dataframe['no'] = dataframe['textblock'].str.findall(pat)
df = dataframe.explode('no').groupby(['index', 'textblock', 'no']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
df.columns.name = None
print(df)


   index                                          textblock  1980  2000  2019  \
0    541  2019, 2713, hello there general 3120 1980 to 2020     1     0     1   
1   6361  Here is some more 2000 dummy text 2029 and add...     0     1     0   

   2020  2029  
0     1     0  
1     0     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion:

```
for no in range(1980,2031):
    df[i]=df.textblock.apply(lambda x: x.count(str(i)))
```

Answer (score 0):

`**kwargs` to `assign()` works well

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([{'index' : 541, 'textblock' : '2019, 2713, hello there general 3120 1980 to 2020'}, {'index' : 6361, 'textblock' : 'Here is some more 2000 dummy text 2029 and additional 1975 text'}])
df2 = df.assign(**{str(c):df.textblock.str.count(str(c)) for c in range(2015,2030)})
```

|  | index | textblock | 2015 | 2016 | 2017 | 2018 | 2019 | 2020 | 2021 | 2022 | 2023 | 2024 | 2025 | 2026 | 2027 | 2028 | 2029 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 541 | 2019, 2713, hello there general 3120 1980 to 2020 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 6361 | Here is some more 2000 dummy text 2029 and additional 1975 text | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

#### with user defined function

- in this example, series is passed
- function returns a series (mandatory in this call context)

```
def afunc(s, col):
    return s.str.count(str(col)) + s.str.count("hello") * 100
df = pd.DataFrame([{'index' : 541, 'textblock' : '2019, 2713, hello there general 3120 1980 to 2020'}, {'index' : 6361, 'textblock' : 'Here is some more 2000 dummy text 2029 and additional 1975 text'}])
df2 = df.assign(**{str(c):afunc(df.textblock, c) for c in range(2015,2030)})
```

Comment: Instead of ```df.textblock.str.count(str(c))```, is there a way to have it in a function, because I also wish to do additional computation (such as write the count with occurrence to a file). The function was a simplified example, such that the function is called only once

Comment: have updated with example of calling a function.  You really should not write to a file in this function - pure definition function without side effects is best practice.  Writing to a file should be done after data processing step,  not in data processing step.  good design/coding 101